# Tulasi Vivah references

Tags: vishnu, tulasi

Which Puranas describe Tulasi vivah, celebrated in Shukla Dwadashi of Kartika.

Vishnu tricking Tulasi was discussed in this [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24565/did-lord-vishnu-trick-tulasi-into-having-sex-with-him-in-her-previous-birth?r=SearchResults&s=12%7C32.8515). But looking for references where Vishnu married Tulasi.

Answer (score 0):

> "Tulasī quitted her mortal coil and assumed a divine form, began to
> remain in the breast of Śrī Hari like Śrī Lakṣmī Devī. Hari also went
> with her to Vaikuṇṭha. Thus Lakṣmī, Sarasvatī, Gaṅgā, and Tulasī, all
> the four came so very dear to Hari and are recognised as Īśvarīs."

Chapter 24, Book 9, Devi Bhagavatam

Comment: Thanks. I had references co-founding l confirming tulasi importance to Hari. But question is about reference to wedding between the two. Ganga and Saraswati also dear as in your answer but not they are not Vishnu's wife's.

Comment: @Kanthri - according to Book 9 of Devi Bhagavatam, both Ganga and Saraswati used to Lord Vishnu's wives. They were seperated from him due to a curse.